# select last-child confusion in css

Tags: html, css

```
<a><div class="myDiv"></div></a>
<a><div class="myDiv"></div></a>
<a><div class="myDiv"></div></a>
<a><div class="myDiv"></div></a> // I want this
```

by using myDiv.last-child it doesn't work. I cant use a.last-child because what I want is the div

Comment: Did you really try `myDiv.last-child`? It would select any `<myDiv>` element with a `class` attribute containing the class name`last-child`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
a:last-child div
```

e.g. Find the last `<a>` in whatever container the above snippet is, then apply to the div inside it.

Comment: Whether this works depends completely on context: whether the elements in the code snippet have some siblings after them.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work if you wrap them with `<a>` .

### [Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB9KE/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div class="myDiv">3</div>
<div class="myDiv">4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myDiv:last-child{
    background:red;
}
```